# Отправка сообщений в группу с помощью бота Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Нужно что бы бот отправлял сообщения сразу в несколько каналов, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: `bot.send_message(chat_id=...)`?

Comment: это же чтоб только в один канал отправить

Comment: отправляйте циклом

Comment: Можно пример кода показать пожалуйста? Как в несколько каналов одно и тоже сообщение отправить

Answer (score 0):

```
for chat_id in [123123123, 123124235324, 543523423, 52456435]:
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, "text")
```